# Mleap Calculating Confidence and feature score

Tags: mleap

I was able to successfully serialize a pyspark generated RandomForestModel as Mleap bundle and run it using mleap-runtime.
I want to get the confidence score and score for each feature. Is there a way to achieve that without using any spark dependencies?